BSOD then dotnet workload issues sdk:8 403
I was running dotnet workload update and got a BSOD and now I am getting errors like this when I run things like dotnet --info and dotnet workload list

System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '0x00'
is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
at
System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader&
json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan1 bytes) at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()    at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadManifestReader.Utf8JsonStreamReader.Read() at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadManifestReader.ReadWorkloadManifest(String id, String manifestPath, LocalizationCatalog localizationCatalog, Utf8JsonStreamReader& reader)    at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadManifestReader.ReadWorkloadManifest(String manifestId, Stream manifestStream, Stream localizationStream, String manifestPath)    at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadResolver.LoadManifestsFromProvider(IWorkloadManifestProvider manifestProvider)    at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadResolver.InitializeManifests() at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WorkloadManifestReader.WorkloadResolver.GetAvailableWorkloadDefinitions()+MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator2.MoveNext()    at
System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains[TSource](IEnumerable1 source, TSource value, IEqualityComparer1 comparer)    at
Microsoft.DotNet.Workloads.Workload.VisualStudioWorkloads.GetInstalledWorkloads(IWorkloadResolver
workloadResolver, InstalledWorkloadsCollection installedWorkloads,
Nullable1 sdkFeatureBand)    at Microsoft.DotNet.Workloads.Workload.List.WorkloadInfoHelper.AddInstalledVsWorkloads(IEnumerable1
sdkWorkloadIds)    at
Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.WorkloadCommandParser.ShowWorkloadsInfo(ParseResult
parseResult, WorkloadInfoHelper workloadInfoHelper, IReporter
reporter, String dotnetDir, Boolean showVersion)    at
Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLineInfo.PrintWorkloadsInfo()    at
Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLineInfo.PrintInfo()    at
Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan
startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)    at
Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)

I have

Uninstalled and reinstalled sdk
ran procmon with a filter for dotnet.exe which I can upload somewhere and link in a bit.

The exception doesn't provide the path when trying to read the manifest so finding the right one is difficult. Is there a config or something where I can make the exception be more verbose instead of wading through all the manifest files procmon listed and trying to find the 0 byte corrupted json file.

Here are some ideas:

dotnet workload repair
Go to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.100, then either

Search for *.json and sort by size to find the empty or suspiciously small file, which can be repaired or deleted, or if it's hard to find:
Move/delete all of the manifest files/folders, then reinstall any needed manifests using dotnet workload install



